# How to debug Redis queue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I'm new with **Laravel**, have implemented a queue with **Redis** and **Supervisor** installed to monitor but can't figure out somethings.

The **Supervisor** configuration is:

```
command=php <laravel path>/artisan queue:work --once
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=<laravel path>worker.log
```

**Questions:**

1. Any error produced by a **job** executed by the queue will be stored in worker.log or depending on the error will be stored there or elsewhere?
2. How can I know the data of the **job** that is running?
3. How can know the queue content and if queue is working?
4. How can know if supervisor is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor has built `Laravel Horizon` since `5.5`. This is an absolute must if you have a job/queue-heavy application:

[Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon)

While it takes just a little bit of configuration to get up and running, once you do, you'll have all the metrics and data that you need to monitor and inspect your jobs.

Comment: Thanks **Ohgodwhy**, I setup `Laravel Horizon` and get better information now however this morning all data collected yesterday is gone. I guess `Horizon` show only recent data so now I'm looking to found how keep the data for more time.